# Why doesn't my Webpack bundle return my classes?

Tags: javascript, webpack, umd

I have a classes, each in it's own file, that are bundled with Webpack. I want to be able to import the bundle and use them in both Node and the browser.

My webpack entry file:

```
import myClassA from './myClassA';
import myClassB from './myClassB';
import myClassC from './myClassC';
// more imports...
```

Example class:

```
export default class myClassA {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './import.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    library: 'MyClasses',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  }
};
```

But when I try to use them I only get an empty object and no sign of the classes.

```
console.log(MyClasses); // {}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/293RGSNoZ6XyRyb3m1HP?p=preview)

Where have I gone wrong?